# Evaluate function slow with Match worksheet function referencing multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

Normally, Excel VBA's Evaluate function is a convenient way to get the result of a worksheet formula in VBA without having to put the formula in a worksheet cell. However, I'm finding that if the formula to be evaluated is MATCH function working across multiple columns, it's surprisingly slow -- MUCH slower than calculating the same formula in a worksheet cell. For example:

```
MatchingRow = EVALUATE(MATCH(Sheet1!G6&Sheet1!H6&Sheet1!I6,Sheet2!B:B&Sheet2!C:C&Sheet2!D:D,0))
```

Any idea why that would be so much slower than this, in a worksheet cell?

```
=MATCH(Sheet1!G6&Sheet1!H6&Sheet1!I6,Sheet2!B:B&Sheet2!C:C&Sheet2!D:D,0)
```

I'm pretty sure I can hear someone already typing an answer saying that it's all because of the overhead of calling a worksheet function from the VBA environment. But if that's the case, my followup question is: *Why isn't EVALUATE slow for other functions too?*

Comment: If I had to guess, it's because EVALUATE treats your formula as if it's an array formula.  Whole column references (like Sheet2!B:B&Sheet2!C:C&'Sheet2!D:D) are slowing it way down.  As a test, try setting the whole column references to be closer to the actual ranges you need to evaluate and see if you get better performance.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/evaluate-functions-and-formulas-fun-how-to-make-excels-evaluate-method-twice-as-fast/) post by Charles Williams. Among other interesting observations, he supports that `Application.Evaluate` is called twice, (it is a bug) compared to `Worksheetfunction.Evaluate`.

Comment: sous2817: thanks, that improved performance by a factor of about 10,000.

Comment: loannis: Thanks, that was an interesting post that you linked to.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things.

Scope is important when using Evaluate(). Calling the method on a worksheet is roughly twice as fast as simply using Evaluate() by itself, which is shorthand for Application.Evaluate().

Concatenation is notoriously slow, and that inefficiency is multiplied when calling through the barrier between VBA and Excel.

This reworking of the formula using Boolean logic as an alternative mechanism to arrive at the same formula result, executes quicker and is much closer in time to a worksheet-housed formula:

```
 MatchingRow =  = Sheet1.[MATCH(1,(Sheet1!G6=Sheet2!B:B)*(Sheet1!H6=Sheet2!C:C)*(Sheet1!I6=Sheet2!D:D),0)]
```

**UPDATE**

For completeness, you should also strongly consider limiting the depth of your lookup ranges. This will dramatically speed up the formula evaluation either on the worksheet or from VBA. Here is the same formula as above, but with the lookup ranges restricted to just 100 rows. Adjust as appropriate:

```
Sheet1.[MATCH(1,(Sheet1!G6=Sheet2!B1:B100)*(Sheet1!H6=Sheet2!C1:C100)*(Sheet1!I6=Sheet2!D1:D100),0)]
```

Comment: Thanks, using the worksheet's Evaluate method was nearly twice as fast as the Application's Evaluate method, and multiplying the separate boolean results of each of the columns improved performance further by a factor of about 3. Also it's an interesting way to use MATCH. I have to say, though, that sous2817's suggestion of restricting the ranges to the actual ranges needed instead of referencing whole columns, improved performance by a factor of about 10,000. So I'd have to consider that the answer, or at least a necessary part of the answer.

Comment: Well, the restriction component always applies in all formula situations (with the exception of a very few highly optimized functions like SUMIFS). My answer focused on your particular situation.

Comment: Except that the restriction component didn't matter (was a such a tiny performance hit that I didn't notice it) for the formula in the worksheet cell. I don't agree with your update in that you make it sound equally important in the worksheet cell. It's clearly not. If it were, my original question would have made no sense.

Comment: It is equally important and you should avoid full-column references whenever possible. That said, calling between the two domains, Excel and VBA amplifies the inefficiencies. The divide is like a microscope allowing you to focus on a specific formula by blowing it up (in this case, slowing it down). The inherent inefficiency is more easily seen. Just because you did not notice it on the worksheet side does not mean it was not there. Do it a bunch of times on the worksheet and the same hit will be observed.

Comment: How do you figure it's equally important? If I do it once in VBA and once on the worksheet, the difference in performance is about 10,000 times. If I do it 10 times in VBA and 10 times in the worksheet, the performance difference is still about 10,000 times. If I did it a million times in VBA and a million times in the worksheet, I'd still expect the performance difference to be about 10,000 times. (continued...)

Comment: To your point that if I did it enough times on the worksheet I'd eventually notice that it wasn't quite instantaneous, sure, but if I did it the same number of times in VBA, it would take about 10,000 times longer than that, therefore about 10,000 times more important.

Comment: Are you familiar with PrecisionCalc?